# Nodejs addons error at GetReturnValue().Set()

Tags: c++, node.js

```
    void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

    const String::Utf8Value prefix(isolate, args[0]);
    const int difficulty = args[1].As<Number>()->Value();
    const string solvedPow = solve(string(*prefix).c_str(), difficulty);
    cout << solvedPow << endl;

    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, solvedPow).ToLocalChecked()); // Error cannot convert
    // argument 2 from const std::string to const char *
}
```

I am really confused on why this is happening, any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Also, just to clarify, no, I'm not mining for cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V8's [`String::NewFromUtf8`](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.15/d2/db3/classv8_1_1_string.html#a9d50737bcffa24e9047dd064d31f624a) takes `const char *` as it's `data` parameter.

In your case `solvedPow` appears to be `std::string`.

These are incompatible types.

You can get a `const char *` from `std::string` using [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```
 args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, solvedPow.c_str()).ToLocalChecked());
```